# Word 2010: Find a single word at the end of the line

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, wildcards

Is there a way to find any lines in a Word document then end with a single woes at the end of the visible line?

This example if of **one line**, and I want to find it in a whole document, as it ends with a single word at the last visible line.
[image]
Also, is there a way to find a certain word "minim", given that it shows at the end of the visible line?  And ignore it if it shows in the middle of any line?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

What you are seeing as a "line" in a document is based on the margin settings of the document and the text dynamically wraps to the next line based on available space. There is not a character in the text line that is forcing the wrap, thus there is nothing that can be searched and found.

Regarding line breaks, MS-Word only allows wildcard searches for words followed by a paragraph character or line feed character.

Comment: While I technically agree with you (and you are right), if someone was inclined to try this using the document setup as it appears on their screen, they can do this via the end key and move left methods.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @rich that this is not technically possible as it depends on the document settings for margins and font sizes, etc., and will be different between computers.

However, if that does not matter to you, you can try to work something out using a macro.

Note that you would have to examine each line (not covered here) until the end of the document.
And also be wary of highlighting only punctuation and repeating steps for a single line if needed.

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy
' here check for word - make sure to remove punctuation as needed
' continue to next line and repeat
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy
' here check for word - make sure to remove punctuation as needed
' you will have to MoveLeft again if you did select punctuation
```

Comment: I tried to create a macro and did record, and it copies the text above to the NewMacros code page, but when clicking on the button I get an error" the macro cannot run", and in Microsoft Visual Basic I get an error "Compile error".  Can you tell me what is the right way to add it?

Comment: My guess is you have a bad call or syntax somewhere.  Try stepping through the code via F8 and it should crap out on the offending line and give you a better idea.  Otherwise, edit your original question and post your code.